# Android Studio Double Value Event Listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all hello guys. I am trying to do if bolum == duyuruBolum then i can get the datas from firebase. I can't use double value event listener because when i do that i just get the bolum data. I want to take both of them. What should i do?

This is my function:

```
public void bolumKontrol() {
    Duyuru duyuru = new Duyuru();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ogrenciRef = rootRef.child("Ogrenci");
    DatabaseReference duyuruRef = rootRef.child("Duyuru");
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uid = user.getUid();
    final String pid = duyuru.getPid();

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String bolum = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("bolumler").getValue(String.class);
                String duyuruBolum = dataSnapshot.child(pid).child("bolum").getValue(String.class);
                if (bolum.equals(duyuruBolum)) {
                    getDataFromFirebase();
                }
                Toast.makeText(OgrenciDuyuruActivity.this,duyuruBolum + bolum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    ogrenciRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
    duyuruRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Here the link https://hizliresim.com/vdmla0 and i want to get Duyuru.bolum, Ogrenci.bolumler and if this two is equals then i will call a function.

Comment: In `Duyuru` node as well in `Ogrenci` node, there are multiple elements, on which one of them would you like to have the equality?

Comment: i said it already it is duyuru.bolum and ogrenci.bolumler